# Rxjs: The scan operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-template, angular2-directives, rxjs5

I have been reading this code if I will replace scan with map I get can not get property "getTime" of undefined, why is it happening I assume that both operator takes an item emits from observable and apply some function on it

```
this.clock = Observable.merge(
        this.click$,
        Observable.interval(5000)
    )
        .startWith(new Date())
        .map((acc : Date)=> {
            const date = new Date(acc.getTime());
             date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 1);
            return date;
        });
```

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(acc)`?

Comment: its displaying undefined

Comment: Please have a look at the following suggestions for debugging questions : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Second advice is to not assume something, but to read the documentation of the functions you are using : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/scan.md for rxjs v4. Note that for Rxjs v2, the seed comes first

Comment: I m trying to understand this code

Answer (score 0):

Because you merge two streams into a single one. You will receive events from `click$` or `interval`. In these cases, they aren't of type Date so you can use the `getTime` method.

The `scan` operator allows keeping a state between events. The `map` one simply converts an input into an output. In the case of the last one, you will receive the event itself...

Comment: What does it mean scan operator keeps a state between events

Comment: I assume that .startWith(new Date()) emitting a date object and map will receive it so getTime should be read on acc

Comment: Yes but it's only for the first event... So it will initialize the value received first by the scan callback.

Comment: What Im assuming that code will start execution from startwith operator this will emit a date object which will go to map function(actually there was scan operator instead of map i replaced just for sake of understanding) because its type of Date, it should read getTime() (but there is error can not read property)

Comment: and the merge operator merging existing subject observable and interval(I assume that interval is used only for delaying it to 5 sec) and this will received by map function on second iteration

Comment: Perhaps this link could help you to understand: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754.

Comment: When you merge streams, the new / resulting stream will receive events from them... You will receive corresponding values within operator callbacks. With scan, you have an additional parameter to handle a kind of context across events.

Comment: Okay so with scan we will have a context that acc is of type Date otherwise threre will be no way to recognize this, e.g with map

Comment: It means that we have maintained the state of acc as Date object, M i right?